# dictConfig can't resolve custom handler due to circular import but does resolve custom formatter

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to register a custom handler and a custom formatter via dictConfig for my project, and I'm getting a an error due to a circular import when registering the custom handler only - the formatter is registered without any issues. This makes no sense, since if there is a circular import both should fail. What am I missing here?

Here are the custom handler and formatter classes (living in `shared.logger.py`):

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

import settings


class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        original_fmt = self._style._fmt

        # If "caller_info" has been added as an extra attribute to the record, modify the formatting to replace the default name and funcname
        if hasattr(record, "caller_info"):
            caller_info: dict = getattr(record, "caller_info")
            module = caller_info["module"]
            func_name = caller_info["funcname"]
            self._style._fmt = f"%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - myapi.{module} - {func_name} - %(message)s"

        result = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        self._style._fmt = original_fmt
        return result


class MyTimedRotatingFileHander(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def rotation_filename(self, default_name: str) -> str:
        new_name = super().rotation_filename(default_name)
        return new_name.replace(".log", "") + ".log"


def get_logger(name: str) -> logging.Logger:
    logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOG_CONFIG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(f"myapi.{name}")

    return logger
```

And here is the `settings.py` file:

```py
import logging

LOG_CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "class": "shared.logger.MyFormatter",
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "class": "shared.logger.MyTimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "level": logging.DEBUG,
            "formatter": "default",
            "filename": "logs/myapi.log",
            "when": "d",
            "interval": 1,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "backupCount": 10,
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "myapi": {
            "level": logging.DEBUG,
            "handlers": ["file"],
            "propagate": False,
        }
    },
}
```

This fails with the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared.logger.MyTimedRotatingFileHandler'; 'shared.logger' is not a package`

The reason I know this is due to circular import is that removing `import settings` and `get_logger()` from `shared.logger.py` eliminates the issue.

But what is really strange here is that if I use a default handler instead of a custom one, there is no error at all - i.e. the custom Formatter is registered despite the circular import! How is this even possible?

Comment: Rename `shared.logger.py` to `shared_logger.py` and change the code to match. What happens then?

Comment: Nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly because of a typo - your class is named `MyTimedRotatingFileHander`, notice `Hander` rather than `Handler`.

Also, don't use dots in Python filenames like `shared.logger.py` - it can cause problems. For example, if you had `shared.logger.py` and side-by-side there was a `shared` directory with an `__init__.py` and a `logger.py` - how would Python be able to resolve which module `shared.logger` is? I recommend using e.g. `shared_logger.py`. In any case, what you are doing is an antipattern - logging configuration should only be done in a `__name__ == '__main__'` clause or `main()` function, not in some library function that could be called multiple times.

Comment: I can't believe I haven't seen the typo! Looked it over a thousand times... I feel dumb.

In any case, I should have made it clear that `shared` is a package, so the file is actually `logger.py`.

As for it being an antipattern, thank you for the call out. You're absolutely right!